# Flutter Add action icons to AppBar while using go_router

Tags: flutter, flutter-go-router

I want to add action icons to my AppBar as shown in this [Flutter example](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/AppBar-class.html)
However I'm using go_flutter and I can't see any property in the MaterialApp.router constructor that would allow to insert icon widgets.
Here's my code so far. How can I add action icons from here ?

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
    const MyApp({super.key});

    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp.router(
            title: 'My App',
            routerConfig: _router,
            debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        );  
    }   
}


final GoRouter _router = GoRouter(routes: [
    GoRoute(path: '/', builder: ((context, state) => Loading())),
    GoRoute(name: 'error', path: '/error/:message/:statusCode', builder: (context, state) => CheckError(
        message: state.params['message']!,
        statusCode: state.params['statusCode']!
    )),
    GoRoute(name: 'home', path: '/home', builder: (context, state) {
            Map data = state.extra as Map;
            return Home(data: data);
        },
    ),
]);
```

Comment: can you include how you are navigating between routes?

Comment: @YeasinSheikh With the goNamed method. For instance in the loading page: `context.goNamed('home', extra: data);`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `push` instead of `goNamed`.

```dart
context.push('home', extra: data); // or can be pushNamed
```

Comment: What is the connection with adding icons in the AppBar ? 
Can't you be more specific ?

Comment: the appBar leading Icon render when  we've route previous pages[routes] on navigator stack. You can think as `go` with `pushReplacement`(not the same) and `push` as general push on navigator.

Answer (score 0):

@Duddy67 answering your comment. And extending @Yeasin Sheikh's answer.

I assume you want to have `<-` button in the appBar of the new screen.

- You need to use `context.push()` to add page to the navigation stack.
- If you use `context.go()` you are just replacing the page, so there is no screen to go back to .

---

**Note:** You need to add `appBar: AppBar(title:Text("Home Page"))` inside the scaffold for the `<-` to appear. (*Emphasis on invoking `AppBar` instance not on setting title.*)